# Qt Window with transparent background image

Tags: qt

I placed background image like this:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    QPixmap slika("some_image.png");
    QPalette paleta;
    paleta.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(slika));
    this->setPalette(paleta);
```

If I make this picture transparent, when application loads, it will only blink and disappear. But if I make this image with no transparency, then everything is ok. Why Qt refuses to use transparent image?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your use case for this, but you can also try using `setStyleSheet` method to make background transparent.

```
setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that, but if my image have transparency then my dialog just blinks and disappear (dialog is still opened and activated, only it's hidden, don't know why). If I place solid image with no transparency then it works.

Comment: @Alen I don't have Qt env setup on this machine so I can't be definitive but I think that would be the default behavior as that window is open but you just can't see it as its background is transparent and there is no window frame.

Comment: Background is not fully transparent, it 50% transparent. And when dialog initialize I can see background image for a second and then it disappear.